# python requests post request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

request payload:
(The spaces are suppose to be there)

```
{input01: {Input: "adress", adress: "g", FirstName: "", LastName: ""}, Locale: "en"}
     Locale:"en"
input01:{Input: "adress", adress: "g", FirstName: "", LastName: ""}
  FirstName:""
  adress:"g"
  Input:"adress"
  LastName:"
```

This is my attempt (Which returns a 400).

```
data = {
      "input01": {
        "Input": "adress",
        "adress": "test",
        "FirstName": "",
        "LastName": ""
      },
      "Locale": "en"
    }

r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(str(r.text))
```

Comment: In general 400 means bad request i.e you are missing some data that is to be posted to the url. Check the url and the data to be posted.

Comment: You can't post a nested dictionary. The 'value' for `input01` will be converted to a string containing Python dictionary syntax. Did you mean to post JSON instead? Then use `requests.post(url, json=data)`.

Comment: Unrelated, to the answer, but `"adress"` is bothering me. I can't help but notice that it is spellt wrong, which distracts me from actually reading what is there. Using `"address"` will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not posting JSON. When you pass a dictionary to the `data` argument, it will be encoded to a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request instead, the default encoding for HTML forms.

To post JSON, use the `json` parameter:

```
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
```